# how can I prepend to a document.title string?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

myWebsite

```
document.title += ` ${date}`; // myWebsite 10/12/17
```

How can i do it the other way around

I will like the date to display prior to the title `10/12/17 myWebsite`

Lodash, solution is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [addition assignment (+=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment), which appends the new string to the end of the existing string. Instead of using the addition assignment, you should manually order the strings.

You can set the the expressions in the correct order in the template string:

```
document.title = `${date} ${document.title}`;
```

Or use string concatenation:

```
document.title = date + ' ' + document.title;
```